# Compare PSCustomObject to Object

Tags: powershell, pscustomobject

I have created a `PsCustomObject`, when the variable is called is ISE, it reads a table of the relevant data. However, if I try to compare the `PsCustomObject` with another object, the `PsCustomObject` doesn't read correctly. I'd like to tell the script if any of the lines in the existing CSV match the `PSCustomObject` do not export the data to the CSV, in other words skip duplicate rows in the CSV file. The CSV may or may not have multiple rows.

```
$fileInfo = @(
                        [pscustomobject]@{
                            user_id = $user
                            studio = $studio
                            function = $Task
                            end_time_local = $creationTime
                            asin = $ASIN
                            variant = $variant
                            process_class_id = $processClass
                            }
                           )
$currentData = Import-Csv "$scansFolder\$fileName.csv"
if($fileInfo -ne $currentData){
$fileInfo | Export-Csv "$scansFolder\$fileName.csv" -Append -NoTypeInformation -Force
}
```

Comment: what is the structure of the imported CSV? if they are the same, then use the `Compare-Object` cmdlet.

Comment: Your `$fileInfo` variable is an _array_. Do you need to support _multiple_ custom objects to exclude from the CSV?

Comment: @Lee_Dailey The csv is the same as the custom object, with headers and the 7 items mentioned in `$fileInfo`.

Comment: @mklement0 I think that may be the problem, i tried something like the following with no luck.

    `foreach($line in $currentData){
    if($fileInfo -ne $currentData){
$fileInfo | Export-Csv "$scansFolder\$fileName.csv" -Append -NoTypeInformation -Force
    }}`

Any ideas on how to do that?

Comment: @Garrett - you can use the `Compare-Object` cmdlet to find out if ONE object is in a collection of similar objects. take a look at the `-IncludeEqual` parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[pscustomobject]` is a .NET *reference* type, so comparing two instances<sup>[1]</sup> with `-eq` will test for *reference equality* (identity), i.e. if the two instances are *one and the same object*<sup>[2]</sup> - which is obviously not the case in your scenario.

Assuming that the *properties* of your custom objects are instances of *value types* or *strings* (which appears to be the case), you can use [`Compare-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/compare-object) to compare objects by their *property values*, with the ability to compare *two collections*:

```
$fileInfo = @(
  [pscustomobject]@{
      user_id = $user
      studio = $studio
      function = $Task
      end_time_local = $creationTime
      asin = $ASIN
      variant = $variant
      process_class_id = $processClass
      }
)

# Get the property names.
# This assumes that the CSV data has (at least) the same
# set of properties (columns).
$propNames = $fileInfo[0].psobject.properties.Name

$currentData = Import-Csv "$scansFolder\$fileName.csv"

# Compare the $fileInfo custom object(s) to the custom objects read
# from the CSV file and only export those that are unique to the RHS ('=>')
# back to the file, i.e., those that don't match $fileInfo.
Compare-Object -Property $propNames $fileInfo $currentData |
  Where-Object SideIndicator -eq '=>' | Select-Object InputObject | 
    Export-Csv "$scansFolder\$fileName.csv" -Append -NoTypeInformation -Force
```

---

<sup>[1] `Import-Csv` outputs `[pscustomobject]` instances too.</sup>

<sup>[2] See the [Equality Comparison](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/equality-comparisons) help topic (written for C#, but applies analogously to PowerShell's `-eq` operator).</sup>

Comment: Here is what `$propName` and `$currentData` are returning when i call them. 

`here is the propNames user_id studio function end_time_local asin variant process_class_id 

here is the currentData @{user_id=tuggleg; studio=SDF8; function=Photo+TT; end_time_local=4/10/2019 16:02; asin=B07G4C5WQR; variant=MAIN; process_class_id=410}`

This script runs as a scheduled task, and pulls specified data from the files in a given path and should write the new info to the csv. But not duplicate and log the same file on each pass.The two outputs don't seem to line up, maybe I am reading it wrong.

Comment: @Garrett: So the property names match. I'm unclear on how you're planning to check for duplicates: your question uses a `[pscustomobject]` literal to compare against the CSV data, and that's what my answer shows you how to do. Are you saying that `$fileInfo` comes from a _different_ file? Or do you need to weed out duplicates _inside a given file_? How do you determine what's new?

Comment: Thanks for your patience. The Scheduled task will run every x # of minutes. I'd like the script to do a `Get-Childitem` to identify the filetypes in a particular path, and pull the $fileInfo from each file and write it to a CSV doc if the `$fileInfo` is unique.

The `Get-Childitem` will continuously see the same files so before writing the info to the CSV i'd like it to read the CSV to pull the `$currentData` and only add 'new' `$fileInfo`.

I think the problem is that i'm not currently comparing the `$fileInfo` for each file to each row in the CSV doc.

Comment: @Garrett, I'm still not sure I fully understand, but you can read multiple CSV files into `$fileInfo` with a single `Import-Csv` call, using something like `Import-Csv -LiteralPath (Get-Item *.csv)` (using  _string_ `*.csv` may not work, due this [this bug](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/6583)), and compare that to the objects in the reference CSV file read into `$currentData` via `Compare-Object`, as shown.

Comment: Sorry I'm having a hard time explaining. Simply put I want to use `export-csv` to write data to a csv, based on `Get-ChildItem` on a path that will contain increasingly more files throughout the day. However, I want to skip duplicate rows of data. If each of the parameters I am pulling and writing to the csv (`$user`, `$studio` etc) are the same, I do not want to write it. I want to avoid writing all data over and over and then filter by  `-unique` at end of day as this would become a problem with large amounts of files.

Comment: @Garrett, you're probably better off keeping track _persistently_ of which files you've already processed, especially as the number of files grows larger, along with the output CSV file growing. Apart from that, what I recommended in my previous comment should work: read all input CSV files into `$fileInfo` - `$fileInfo = Import-Csv -LiteralPath (Get-Item c:\path\to\inputs\*.csv)` - then use the `Compare-Object` call against `$currentData`, as shown in the answer.

Comment: Generally, I suggest we bring closure to this question: my answer addresses your question _as asked_, so I suggest you accept it; if there are follow-up questions, please create a _new_ question (feel free to ping me here once you've done so).

Comment: Based on above suggestions, im going a new route with this script. I believe mklement0 answered the original question.