# Powershell eq operator saying hashes are different, while Write-Host is showing the opposite

Tags: powershell

I have a script that periodically generates a list of all files in a directory, and then writes a text file of the results to a different directory.

I'd like to change this so it checks the newest text file in the output directory, and only makes a new one if there's differences. It seemed simple enough.

Here's what I tried:

First I get the most recent file in the directory, grab the hash, and write my variable values to the console:

```
$lastFile = gci C:\ReportOutputDir | sort LastWriteTime | select -last 1 | Select-Object -ExpandProperty FullName
$oldHash = Get-FileHash $lastFile | Select-Object Hash
Write-Host 'lastFile = '$lastFile
Write-Host 'oldHash = '$oldHash
```

Output:

```
lastFile = C:\ReportOutputDir\test1.txt
oldHash =  @{Hash=E7787C54F5BAE236100A24A6F453A5FDF6E6C7333B60ED8624610EAFADF45521}
```

Then I do the exact same gci on the FileList dir, and create a new file (new_test.txt), then grab the hash of this file:

```
gci -Path C:\FileLists -File -Recurse -Name -Depth 2 | Sort-Object | out-file C:\ReportOutputDir\new_test.txt
$newFile = gci C:\ReportOutputDir | sort LastWriteTime | select -last 1 | Select-Object -ExpandProperty FullName
$newHash = Get-FileHash $newFile | Select-Object Hash
Write-Host 'newFile = '$newFile
Write-Host 'newHash = '$newHash
```

Output:

```
newFile =  C:\ReportOutputDir\new_test.txt
newHash =  @{Hash=E7787C54F5BAE236100A24A6F453A5FDF6E6C7333B60ED8624610EAFADF45521}
```

Finally, I attempt my -eq operator where I'd usually simply remove the newFile if it's equal. For now, I'm just doing a simple :

```
if ($newHash -eq $oldHash){
'files are equal'
}
else {'files are not equal'}
```

And somehow, I'm getting

```
files are not equal
```

What gives? Also, for the record I was originally trying to save the gci output to a variable and comparing the contents of the last file to the gci output, but was also having trouble with the -eq operator. Fairly new to powershell stuff so I'm sure I'm doing something wrong here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- **`Select-Object Hash` creates an *object* with a `.Hash` property** and it is that property that contains the hash *string*.
- The object returned is of type `[pscustomobject]`, and two instances of this type *never* compare as equal - even if all their property names and values are equal:

  - The reason is that *reference equality* is tested, because `[pscustomobject]` is a .NET *reference type* that doesn't define *custom* equality-testing logic.
  - Testing reference equality means that only two references *to the very same instance*  compare as equal.
  - A quick example:

    ```sh
    PS> [pscustomobject] @{ foo = 1 } -eq [pscustomobject] @{ foo = 1 }
    False # !! Two distinct instances aren't equal, no matter what they contain.
    ```

---

You have two options:

- **Compare the `.Hash` property values**, not the objects as a whole:

  ```sh
  if ($newHash.Hash -eq $oldHash.Hash) { # ...
  ```
- If you don't need a `[pscustomobject]` wrapper for the hash strings, **use [`Select-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object)'s `-ExpandProperty` parameter** instead of the (possibly positionally implied) `-Property` parameter:

  ```sh
  Select-Object -ExpandProperty Hash
  ```

---

As for why the `Write-Host` output matched:

When you force objects to be converted to *string* representations - essentially, [`Write-Host`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/write-host) calls `.ToString()` on its arguments - the string representations of distinct `[pscustomobject]` instances that have the same properties and values will be the same:

```sh
PS> "$([pscustomobject] @{ foo = 1 })" -eq "$([pscustomobject] @{ foo = 1 })"
True # Same as: '@{foo=1}' -eq '@{foo=1}'
```

However, **you should *not* rely on these hashtable-*like* string representations** to determine equality of `[pscustomobject]`s as a whole, because of the inherent limitations of these representations, which **can easily yield false positives**.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55691362/45375) shows how to **compare `[pscustomobject]` instances *as a whole***, by comparing all of their property values, by passing all property names to [`Compare-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/compare-object) `-Property` - but note that this assumes that all property values are either strings or instances of .NET value types or corresponding properties must again either reference the very same instance of a .NET reference type or be of a type  that implements custom equality-comparison logic.